# Grabbing a data from wp_usermeta

Tags: customization

I installed a new plugin and it created some meta data for me in the `wp_usermeta` table

`meta_value a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:7:"site_id";i:1;s:5:"posts";a:2:{i:0;i:4;i:1;i:178;}}}`

A few questions:

1. what kind of data format is this?
2. what is a:1 and a:2?
3. the values im trying to grab are 4 and 178.  How would i go about pulling this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is PHP serialized data. It is how PHP creates a storable version of data that retains its structure.

Don't try to work directly with data in the database, use API functions like [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) and you don't have to worry about how it is stored.